# How do I use custom keys with Swift 4's Decodable protocol?

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable

Swift 4 introduced support for native JSON encoding and decoding via the [`Decodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) protocol. How do I use custom keys for this?

E.g., say I have a struct

```
struct Address:Codable {
    var street:String
    var zip:String
    var city:String
    var state:String
}
```

I can encode this to JSON.

```
let address = Address(street: "Apple Bay Street", zip: "94608", city: "Emeryville", state: "California")

if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(address) {
    if let json = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8) {
        // Print JSON String
        print(json)

        // JSON string is 
           { "state":"California", 
             "street":"Apple Bay Street", 
             "zip":"94608", 
             "city":"Emeryville" 
           }
    }
}
```

I can encode this back to an object.

```
    let newAddress: Address = try decoder.decode(Address.self, from: encoded)
```

But If I had a json object that was

```
{ 
   "state":"California", 
   "street":"Apple Bay Street", 
   "zip_code":"94608", 
   "city":"Emeryville" 
}
```

How would I tell the decoder on `Address` that `zip_code` maps to `zip`? I believe you use the new `CodingKey` protocol, but I can't figure out how to use this.

Answer (score 359, accepted):

#### Manually customising coding keys

In your example, you're getting an auto-generated conformance to [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) as all your properties also conform to `Codable`. This conformance automatically creates a key type that simply corresponds to the property names – which is then used in order to encode to/decode from a single keyed container.

However one *really* neat feature of this auto-generated conformance is that if you define a nested `enum` in your type called "`CodingKeys`" (or use a `typealias` with this name) that conforms to the [`CodingKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codingkey) protocol – Swift will automatically use *this* as the key type. This therefore allows you to easily customise the keys that your properties are encoded/decoded with.

So what this means is you can just say:

```
struct Address : Codable {

    var street: String
    var zip: String
    var city: String
    var state: String

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case street, zip = "zip_code", city, state
    }
}
```

The enum case names need to match the property names, and the raw values of these cases need to match the keys that you're encoding to/decoding from (unless specified otherwise, the raw values of a `String` enumeration will the same as the case names). Therefore, the `zip` property will now be encoded/decoded using the key `"zip_code"`.

The exact rules for the auto-generated [`Encodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable)/[`Decodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) conformance are detailed by [the evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0166-swift-archival-serialization.md) (emphasis mine):

> In addition to automatic `CodingKey` requirement synthesis for
>   `enums`, `Encodable` & `Decodable` requirements can be automatically
>   synthesized for certain types as well:
>
> 1. Types conforming to `Encodable` whose properties are all `Encodable` get an automatically generated `String`-backed `CodingKey` enum mapping
>      properties to case names. Similarly for `Decodable` types whose
>      properties are all `Decodable`
> 2. Types falling into (1) — **and types which manually provide a `CodingKey` `enum` (named `CodingKeys`, directly, or via a `typealias`) whose
>      cases map 1-to-1 to `Encodable`/`Decodable` properties by name** — get
>      automatic synthesis of `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` as appropriate,
>      using those properties and keys
> 3. Types which fall into neither (1) nor (2) will have to provide a custom key type if needed and provide their own `init(from:)` and
>      `encode(to:)`, as appropriate

Example encoding:

```
import Foundation

let address = Address(street: "Apple Bay Street", zip: "94608",
                      city: "Emeryville", state: "California")

do {
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(address)
    print(String(decoding: encoded, as: UTF8.self))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
//{"state":"California","street":"Apple Bay Street","zip_code":"94608","city":"Emeryville"}
```

Example decoding:

```
// using the """ multi-line string literal here, as introduced in SE-0168,
// to avoid escaping the quotation marks
let jsonString = """
{"state":"California","street":"Apple Bay Street","zip_code":"94608","city":"Emeryville"}
"""

do {
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Address.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    print(decoded)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

// Address(street: "Apple Bay Street", zip: "94608",
// city: "Emeryville", state: "California")
```

---

#### Automatic `snake_case` JSON keys for `camelCase` property names

In Swift 4.1, if you rename your `zip` property to `zipCode`, you can take advantage of the key encoding/decoding strategies on `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` in order to automatically convert coding keys between `camelCase` and `snake_case`.

Example encoding:

```
import Foundation

struct Address : Codable {
  var street: String
  var zipCode: String
  var city: String
  var state: String
}

let address = Address(street: "Apple Bay Street", zipCode: "94608",
                      city: "Emeryville", state: "California")

do {
  let encoder = JSONEncoder()
  encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
  let encoded = try encoder.encode(address)
  print(String(decoding: encoded, as: UTF8.self))
} catch {
  print(error)
}
//{"state":"California","street":"Apple Bay Street","zip_code":"94608","city":"Emeryville"}
```

Example decoding:

```
let jsonString = """
{"state":"California","street":"Apple Bay Street","zip_code":"94608","city":"Emeryville"}
"""

do {
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
  let decoded = try decoder.decode(Address.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
  print(decoded)
} catch {
  print(error)
}

// Address(street: "Apple Bay Street", zipCode: "94608",
// city: "Emeryville", state: "California")
```

One important thing to note about this strategy however is that it won't be able to round-trip some property names with acronyms or initialisms which, according to the [Swift API design guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#general-conventions), should be uniformly upper or lower case (depending on the position).

For example, a property named `someURL` will be encoded with the key `some_url`, but on decoding, this will be transformed to `someUrl`.

To fix this, you'll have to manually specify the coding key for that property to be string that the decoder expects, e.g `someUrl` in this case (which will still be transformed to `some_url` by the encoder):

```
struct S : Codable {

  private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case someURL = "someUrl", someOtherProperty
  }

  var someURL: String
  var someOtherProperty: String
}
```

---

<sub>(This doesn't strictly answer your specific question, but given the canonical nature of this Q&A, I feel it's worth including)</sub>

#### Custom automatic JSON key mapping

In Swift 4.1, you can take advantage of the custom key encoding/decoding strategies on `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder`, allowing you to provide a custom function to map coding keys.

The function you provide takes a `[CodingKey]`, which represents the coding path for the current point in encoding/decoding (in most cases, you'll only need to consider the last element; that is, the current key). The function returns a `CodingKey` that will replace the last key in this array.

For example, `UpperCamelCase` JSON keys for `lowerCamelCase` property names:

```
import Foundation

// wrapper to allow us to substitute our mapped string keys.
struct AnyCodingKey : CodingKey {

  var stringValue: String
  var intValue: Int?

  init(_ base: CodingKey) {
    self.init(stringValue: base.stringValue, intValue: base.intValue)
  }

  init(stringValue: String) {
    self.stringValue = stringValue
  }

  init(intValue: Int) {
    self.stringValue = "\(intValue)"
    self.intValue = intValue
  }

  init(stringValue: String, intValue: Int?) {
    self.stringValue = stringValue
    self.intValue = intValue
  }
}
```

```
extension JSONEncoder.KeyEncodingStrategy {

  static var convertToUpperCamelCase: JSONEncoder.KeyEncodingStrategy {
    return .custom { codingKeys in

      var key = AnyCodingKey(codingKeys.last!)

      // uppercase first letter
      if let firstChar = key.stringValue.first {
        let i = key.stringValue.startIndex
        key.stringValue.replaceSubrange(
          i ... i, with: String(firstChar).uppercased()
        )
      }
      return key
    }
  }
}
```

```
extension JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy {

  static var convertFromUpperCamelCase: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy {
    return .custom { codingKeys in

      var key = AnyCodingKey(codingKeys.last!)

      // lowercase first letter
      if let firstChar = key.stringValue.first {
        let i = key.stringValue.startIndex
        key.stringValue.replaceSubrange(
          i ... i, with: String(firstChar).lowercased()
        )
      }
      return key
    }
  }
}
```

You can now encode with the `.convertToUpperCamelCase` key strategy:

```
let address = Address(street: "Apple Bay Street", zipCode: "94608",
                      city: "Emeryville", state: "California")

do {
  let encoder = JSONEncoder()
  encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToUpperCamelCase
  let encoded = try encoder.encode(address)
  print(String(decoding: encoded, as: UTF8.self))
} catch {
  print(error)
}
//{"Street":"Apple Bay Street","City":"Emeryville","State":"California","ZipCode":"94608"}
```

and decode with the `.convertFromUpperCamelCase` key strategy:

```
let jsonString = """
{"Street":"Apple Bay Street","City":"Emeryville","State":"California","ZipCode":"94608"}
"""

do {
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromUpperCamelCase
  let decoded = try decoder.decode(Address.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
  print(decoded)
} catch {
  print(error)
}

// Address(street: "Apple Bay Street", zipCode: "94608",
// city: "Emeryville", state: "California")
```

Comment: Just stumbled on to this myself! I wonder, is there a way to only override the one key that I want to change and leave the rest alone? E.g. in the case statement, under the `CodingKeys` enum; can I just list the one key I'm changing?

Comment: `"""` is for a *multi-line* literal :)

Comment: @MartinR Or even just a single line literal without having to escape `"`s :D

Comment: @chrismanderson I don't believe so, but really I don't think it's too onerous.

Comment: It's not that bad. It does make it safe, so you ensure that ever key is covered. It will be easier to handle in Xcode 9 for sure with refactoring. It is a duplicate list, which is never a great thing. But as you said, it's not the worst thing in the world.

Comment: @chrismanderson Exactly – especially given that the compiler enforces that the case names are kept in sync with the property names (it will give you an error saying you're not conforming to `Codable` otherwise)

Comment: do you by any chance know if it's possible to use nested keys like `address.street`?

Comment: @NikGreen Not quite sure I understand – each nesting layer should really be responsible for managing its own keys (be it auto-generated by the compiler, or specified manually), independent of other layers. Could you possibly give an example of what you mean? If you just mean extracting the value for the `street` key from the `Address`, I would just do `JSONDecoder().decode(Address.self, from: jsonData).street`. You probably could use nested types in order to do for example `.decode(Address.Street.self, from: jsonData)`, but I don't immediately see how you could do that without duplicating keys

Comment: @Hamish I think what @NikGreen means is asking is, can you skip to a nested object using nested keys in JSON in order to avoid creating `struct`s for each layer? So that in the nested `CodingKeys` `enum` you could specify `case address = "person.house.address"` (in some `Codable`) without having to create `Person` and `House` `struct`s if the JSON had an `Address` nested under `{ "person": { ... "house": { ... "address": { "state":... } } } }`.

Comment: Okay, this page makes it pretty clear how to handle that case: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types. See specifically "Encode and Decode Manually" where it talks about `additionalInfo`.

Comment: @ClayEllis Ah yes, although of course using the nested containers for example directly in the initialiser of `Address` unnecessarily ties yourself to decoding a JSON object that starts at a specific place in the parent object graph. It would be much nicer to abstract the starting key path up to the decoder itself – here's [a rough hackey-ish implementation](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/6840442a3195da64bb01004f6bc6c31e).

Comment: i have to parse {"Accept-Encoding" = ""} and i simply cannot name a var or let like Accept-Encoding because of the '-' character. I keep getting compiler error so this answer the solution of my problem. It's so boring that we can name a variable using emoji but we can't use '-' character.

Comment: I have a snake case value in an API that is `percent_change_24h`. Using `.convertFromSnakeCase` I tried `percentChange24h` but I'm getting nil. My other snake cases without numerals work i.e. `market_cap` to `marketCap` so this seems to be an issue with numerals.

Comment: @tymac `convertFromSnakeCase` internally appears to use the `.capitalized` property on `(NS)String` in order to transform each of the non-first components (those separated by underscores) of the key. `"24h".capitalized` returns `"24H"`, so you want `percentChange24H` (you can add this as a custom coding key if you want your property to remain being named `percentChange24h`).

Comment: @Hamish What's weird is that I already created a custom coding key using `case volume24h = "volume_24h"` but I was still seeing nil in the output. Any ideas why? I did however have success with changing it to uppercase like you said. Amazing! Where did you find that info about the internal info? Thanks.

Comment: @tymac Custom coding keys are consulted *after* performing any given key strategies, so you want `case volume24h = "volume24H"`. And the implementation of the `convertFromSnakeCase` key strategy is [available here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/fc99de452d7457026a863f5a77f84d72fb45e8c7/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L1009) :)

Comment: Great code, thank you @Hamish . Do you mind updating the extension JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy convertFromUpperCamelCase to swift 4.2 ? I'm trying to do something similar and AnyCodingKey() doesn't exist anymore. Also when I try to replaceSubrange on the key, I get an error saying: "cannot use mutating member on immutable value". I'm trying to use a .custom KeyDecodingStrategy to implement an UPPERCASEKeyCodable extension. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: On an update, I managed to do something with it. There is some help here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/custom And there is a custom AnyKey struct and that is used there. This code & help is still appreciated

Comment: @c1pherB1t The code in my answer compiles fine in Swift 4.2 for me. `AnyCodingKey` isn't a part of the standard library (but really it should it be!), I defined it in an earlier code block in my answer.

Comment: @Hamish thank you for the response. Oh yes, I just realized that! AnyCodingKey is pretty similar to AnyKey in that link by Apple. I was also a bit confused by using codingKeys.last but I think that's the way Apple wants to iterate over the keys in the .custom callback. I'm good now. Thanks again.

Comment: @c1pherB1t No worries! `codingKeys.last` gives you current coding key, all the previous elements in the array are parent coding keys for the given coding path. For example when decoding `{"foo": {"bar": "baz"}}`, when the key decoding strategy is applied to `"bar"`, `codingKeys` will be `["foo", "bar"]`.

Comment: upvoted because of encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase :) was looking for the way how to not repeat all properties inside CodingKeys enum. Thanks!

Comment: Just a side note: UpperCamelCase is usually called PascalCase

Comment: This is the best SO answer I've seen for any Swift/JSON question. Thank you so much for the clear and thorough discussion and clean, working examples.

Answer (score 38):

With Swift 4.2, according to your needs, you may use one of the 3 following strategies in order to make your model objects custom property names match your JSON keys.

---

## #1. Using custom coding keys

When you declare a struct that conforms to `Codable` (`Decodable` and `Encodable` protocols) with the following implementation...

```
struct Address: Codable {
    var street: String
    var zip: String
    var city: String
    var state: String        
}
```

... the compiler automatically generates a nested enum that conforms to `CodingKey` protocol for you.

```
struct Address: Codable {
    var street: String
    var zip: String
    var city: String
    var state: String

    // compiler generated
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case street
        case zip
        case city
        case state
    }
}
```

Therefore, if the keys used in your serialized data format don't match the property names from your data type, you can manually implement this enum and set the appropriate `rawValue` for the required cases.

The following example shows how to do:

```
import Foundation

struct Address: Codable {
    var street: String
    var zip: String
    var city: String
    var state: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case street
        case zip = "zip_code"
        case city
        case state
    }
}
```

*Encode (replacing `zip` property with "zip_code" JSON key):*

```
let address = Address(street: "Apple Bay Street", zip: "94608", city: "Emeryville", state: "California")

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(address), let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(jsonString)
}

/*
 prints:
 {"state":"California","street":"Apple Bay Street","zip_code":"94608","city":"Emeryville"}
 */
```

*Decode (replacing "zip_code" JSON key with `zip` property):*

```
let jsonString = """
{"state":"California","street":"Apple Bay Street","zip_code":"94608","city":"Emeryville"}
"""

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8), let address = try? decoder.decode(Address.self, from: jsonData) {
    print(address)
}

/*
 prints:
 Address(street: "Apple Bay Street", zip: "94608", city: "Emeryville", state: "California")
 */
```

---

## #2. Using snake case to camel case key coding strategies

If your JSON has snake-cased keys and you want to convert them to camel-cased properties for your model object, you can set your `JSONEncoder`'s [`keyEncodingStrategy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/2949141-keyencodingstrategy) and `JSONDecoder`'s [`keyDecodingStrategy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2949119-keydecodingstrategy) properties to `.convertToSnakeCase`.

The following example shows how to do:

```
import Foundation

struct Address: Codable {
    var street: String
    var zipCode: String
    var cityName: String
    var state: String
}
```

*Encode (converting camel cased properties into snake cased JSON keys):*

```
let address = Address(street: "Apple Bay Street", zipCode: "94608", cityName: "Emeryville", state: "California")

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase
if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(address), let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(jsonString)
}

/*
 prints:
 {"state":"California","street":"Apple Bay Street","zip_code":"94608","city_name":"Emeryville"}
 */
```

*Decode (converting snake cased JSON keys into camel cased properties):*

```
let jsonString = """
{"state":"California","street":"Apple Bay Street","zip_code":"94608","city_name":"Emeryville"}
"""

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8), let address = try? decoder.decode(Address.self, from: jsonData) {
    print(address)
}

/*
 prints:
 Address(street: "Apple Bay Street", zipCode: "94608", cityName: "Emeryville", state: "California")
 */
```

---

## #3. Using custom key coding strategies

If necessary, `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` allow you to set a custom strategy to map coding keys using [`JSONEncoder.KeyEncodingStrategy.custom(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/keyencodingstrategy/custom) and [`JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy.custom(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/custom).

The following example shows how to implement them:

```
import Foundation

struct Address: Codable {
    var street: String
    var zip: String
    var city: String
    var state: String
}

struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int?

    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    init?(intValue: Int) {
        self.stringValue = String(intValue)
        self.intValue = intValue
    }
}
```

*Encode (converting lowercased first letter properties into uppercased first letter JSON keys):*

```
let address = Address(street: "Apple Bay Street", zip: "94608", city: "Emeryville", state: "California")

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .custom({ (keys) -> CodingKey in
    let lastKey = keys.last!
    guard lastKey.intValue == nil else { return lastKey }
    let stringValue = lastKey.stringValue.prefix(1).uppercased() + lastKey.stringValue.dropFirst()
    return AnyKey(stringValue: stringValue)!
})

if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(address), let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(jsonString)
}

/*
 prints:
 {"Zip":"94608","Street":"Apple Bay Street","City":"Emeryville","State":"California"}
 */
```

*Decode (converting uppercased first letter JSON keys into lowercased first letter properties):*

```
let jsonString = """
{"State":"California","Street":"Apple Bay Street","Zip":"94608","City":"Emeryville"}
"""

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom({ (keys) -> CodingKey in
    let lastKey = keys.last!
    guard lastKey.intValue == nil else { return lastKey }
    let stringValue = lastKey.stringValue.prefix(1).lowercased() + lastKey.stringValue.dropFirst()
    return AnyKey(stringValue: stringValue)!
})

if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8), let address = try? decoder.decode(Address.self, from: jsonData) {
    print(address)
}

/*
 prints:
 Address(street: "Apple Bay Street", zip: "94608", city: "Emeryville", state: "California")
 */
```

---

Sources:

- [Apple developer documentation: "Encoding and Decoding Custom Types"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)
- [WWDC 2017 session 212: "What's new in Foundation"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/)
- [MartianCraft: "Implementing a custom key strategy for coding types"](https://martiancraft.com/blog/2018/08/Implementing-custom-key-strategy-for-coding-types/)

Answer (score 3):

What I have done is create own structure just like what you are getting from the JSON with respect to its data types.

Just like this:

```
struct Track {
let id : Int
let contributingArtistNames:String
let name : String
let albumName :String
let copyrightP:String
let copyrightC:String
let playlistCount:Int
let trackPopularity:Int
let playlistFollowerCount:Int
let artistFollowerCount : Int
let label : String
}
```

After this you need to create an extension of the same `struct` extending `decodable` and the `enum` of the same structure with `CodingKey` and then you need to initialize the decoder using this enum with its keys and datatypes (Keys will come from the enum and the datatypes will be coming or say referenced from the structure itself)

```
extension Track: Decodable {

    enum TrackCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case contributingArtistNames = "primaryArtistsNames"
        case spotifyId = "spotifyId"
        case name = "name"
        case albumName = "albumName"
        case albumImageUrl = "albumImageUrl"
        case copyrightP = "copyrightP"
        case copyrightC = "copyrightC"
        case playlistCount = "playlistCount"
        case trackPopularity = "trackPopularity"
        case playlistFollowerCount = "playlistFollowerCount"
        case artistFollowerCount = "artistFollowers"
        case label = "label"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let trackContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: TrackCodingKeys.self)
        if trackContainer.contains(.id){
            id = try trackContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        }else{
            id = 0
        }
        if trackContainer.contains(.contributingArtistNames){
            contributingArtistNames = try trackContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .contributingArtistNames)
        }else{
            contributingArtistNames = ""
        }
        if trackContainer.contains(.spotifyId){
            spotifyId = try trackContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .spotifyId)
        }else{
            spotifyId = ""
        }
        if trackContainer.contains(.name){
            name = try trackContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        }else{
            name = ""
        }
        if trackContainer.contains(.albumName){
            albumName = try trackContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .albumName)
        }else{
            albumName = ""
        }
        if trackContainer.contains(.albumImageUrl){
            albumImageUrl = try trackContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .albumImageUrl)
        }else{
            albumImageUrl = ""
        }
        if trackContainer.contains(.copyrightP){
            copyrightP = try trackContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .copyrightP)
        }else{
            copyrightP = ""
        }
        if trackContainer.contains(.copyrightC){
                copyrightC = try trackContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .copyrightC)
        }else{
            copyrightC = ""
        }
        if trackContainer.contains(.playlistCount){
            playlistCount = try trackContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .playlistCount)
        }else{
            playlistCount = 0
        }

        if trackContainer.contains(.trackPopularity){
            trackPopularity = try trackContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .trackPopularity)
        }else{
            trackPopularity = 0
        }
        if trackContainer.contains(.playlistFollowerCount){
            playlistFollowerCount = try trackContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .playlistFollowerCount)
        }else{
            playlistFollowerCount = 0
        }

        if trackContainer.contains(.artistFollowerCount){
            artistFollowerCount = try trackContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .artistFollowerCount)
        }else{
            artistFollowerCount = 0
        }
        if trackContainer.contains(.label){
            label = try trackContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .label)
        }else{
            label = ""
        }
    }
}
```

You need to change here each and every key and datatypes according to your needs and use it with the decoder.

Comment: Or you could use ```decodeIfPresent``` : ```label = trackContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .label) ?? ""```

Answer (score 1):

By using **CodingKey** you can use custom keys in codable  or decodable protocol.

```
struct person: Codable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var street: String
    var state: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case age
        case street = "Street_name"
        case state
    } }
```