# How do I convert this JSON into a Swift structure using the Decodable protocol?

Tags: json, swift, codable

**Note**: I have already looked at this question -> [How do I use custom keys with Swift 4's Decodable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396500/how-do-i-use-custom-keys-with-swift-4s-decodable-protocol) But it does not explain how to Encode/Decode enums

Here is the structure I want:

```
struct MyStruct: Decodable {
    let count: PostType
}

enum PostType: Decodable {
    case fast(value: Int, value2: Int)
    case slow(string: String, string2: String)
}
```

Now i know how i want my struct to look, the problem is:

1. I do not know what the `init` function should look like inside of the `PostType` enum.

I use the code below to help me construct the JSON quickly.

```
    let jsonData = """
    {
       "count": {
          "fast" :
           {
               "value": 4,
               "value2": 5
           }
       }
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!

    // Decoding
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let response = try decoder.decode(MyStruct.self, from: jsonData)
        print(response)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

**Edit1** my JSON looks like this

```
   {
        "count": {
           "fast" :
            {
                "value": 4,
                "value2": 5
            }
        }
    }
```

What should the `init` look like in the `PostType enum` ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. That question is decoding a struct. This is decoding an Enum with a tuple. I know how to decode structs, but with an enum it is very different.

Comment: What is your expected JSON representation of the associated enum values?

Comment: @vadian thats the thing. I know that i want my struct to look like `MyStruct`, But i do not know what the JSON should look like. If someone can tell me then i can make the JSON be that value.

Comment: JSON has a limited set of types: `Array`, `Dictionary` as collection types and `String`, `Number`, `Bool` and `null` as value types. You can represent your enum as array of String / Int or each value as key / value pair or as dictionary with the case as key.

Comment: @vadian I have edited my question and included what my JSON looks like. How do i get the PostType enum to parse this?

Comment: I wrote an answer providing several options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since an `enum` with associated types does not match any JSON type you need a bit more handwork and write a custom mapping.

The following code covers three options.

- A dictionary with the case as key and an containing dictionary with parameter labels as keys
- Encoding / Decoding each associated value as separate key / value pair
- Encoding / Decoding all associated values in an array with an arbitrary key.

First of all the enum must not conform to `Codable`

```
enum PostType {
    case fast(value: Int, value2: Int)
    case middle(bool: Bool)
    case slow(string: String, string2: String)
}
```

The case `fast` uses an array, `middle` a sub-dictionary, `slow` separate key / value pairs.

---

Then declare the `MyStruct` struct, adopt `Codable` and declare the `type`

```
struct MyStruct : Codable {
    var type : PostType
```

This solution requires custom keys

```
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case value, string, string2, middle
  }
```

The `encode` method `switch`es on the cases and creates the appropriate types

```
  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
     var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      switch type {
      case .fast(let value, let value2) :
          try container.encode([value, value2], forKey: .value)

      case .slow(let string, let string2) :
          try container.encode(string, forKey: .string)
          try container.encode(string2, forKey: .string2)

      case .middle(let bool):
          try container.encode(["bool" : bool], forKey: .middle)
      }
  }
```

In the `decode` method you can distinguish the cases by the passed keys, make sure that they are unique.

```
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      let allKeys = values.allKeys
      if allKeys.contains(.middle) {
          let value = try values.decode([String:Bool].self, forKey: .middle)
          type = PostType.middle(bool: value["bool"]!)
      } else if allKeys.contains(.value) {
          let value = try values.decode([Int].self, forKey: .value)
          type = PostType.fast(value: value[0], value2: value[1])
      } else {
          let string = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .string)
          let string2 = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .string2)
          type = PostType.slow(string: string, string2: string2)
      }
   }
}
```

Although some keys are hard-coded the first option seems to be the most suitable one.

---

Finally an example to use it:

```
let jsonString = "[{\"value\": [2, 6]}, {\"string\" : \"foo\", \"string2\" : \"bar\"}, {\"middle\" : {\"bool\" : true}}]"

let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyStruct].self, from: jsonData)
    print("decoded:", decoded)

    let newEncoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(decoded)
    print("re-encoded:", String(data: newEncoded, encoding: .utf8)!)

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```