# Can I to declare a variable named 'Type' in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, struct, decode, decodable

I use someone else's API. It is returning me JSON. Like this;

```
[{"ID": 123,
 "Name": "My Game Api",
 "Type": "Racing",
 "Num": 0,
 "Country": "England"
}]
```

I define a struct to parse JSON, like this:

```
struct MyResult : Decodable{
    var ID : Int?
    var Name : String?
    var Type : String?
    var Num : Int?
    var Country : String?
}
// Using..
    let games = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyResult].self, from: data!)
```

Of course xCode gives me an error:
*Type member may not be named 'Type', since it would conflict with the 'foo.Type' expression.*

I did not write the API. 
If I change the name of the variable **Type**, I can not read the value.

Can I use Decodable Struct without modifying the API?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/44396500/2976878. You should use `lowerCamelCase` property names as is Swift convention; and map to your JSON keys in a custom `CodingKeys` enum.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types#2904057

Comment: Also, unrelated, but do all your properties really need to be optional? Is it legal for your JSON to not contain keys for *any* of them?

Comment: As @Hamish has stated, you should be using camelCase variable names and a `CodingKeys` enum. That being said, you can probably still use `Type` as a variable name by surrounding it's declaration with back-ticks (`). I don't recommend this, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like below :

```
struct MyResult : Decodable {
    var ID : Int?
    var Name : String?
    var type : String?
    var Num : Int?
    var Country : String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case ID, Name, type = "Type", Num, Country
    }
}
```

Try to follow the comments posted by `Hamish`

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your types starting with a lowercase letter. And just do the same you did for "Type" for the other properties

Comment: btw you should declare all you struct properties as constants using let and probably none of them needs to be optional