# Get specific CodingKey for KeyPath

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, key-value-coding, codable

Consider the following object:

```
struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let email: String
    let name: String
}
```

Is it posible to get a specific [`CodingKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codingkey) for a given [`KeyPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keypath)?

```
let key = \User.name.codingKey  // would be equal to string: "name"
```

Comment: Autogenerated `CodingKeys` are private to the type, so you won't be able to access them outside of that type. What are you looking to do here?

Comment: @ItaiFerber I don't know about OP's use case, but I also have often required some way to get a `CodingKey` from a `KeyPath`. Most recent use case was building a strongly-typed wrapper around the Firebase Database API, so instead of saying `someRef.child("foo").child("bar").observe(.value) { snapshot in /* snapshot.value is an Any? ew. */}` you would say `someProvider.observeValue(at: \.foo.bar) { value in /* value is typed as whatever the type of bar is */ }`. To implement, had to have each type provide a dictionary that mapped immediate child key paths to coding keys (in a 1:1 manner)...

Comment: ... The coding keys were just typed as `CodingKey`, so `CodingKeys` didn't need to be exposed. Then had to iterate through the entire tree of properties from a given root type, building up a key path and comparing it with the argument; which wasn't ideal. It would certainly be nice if the language provided some way to automatically do that mapping for you; although that being said, I'm not sure it'd be viable for types that implement their own custom encoding/decoding logic.

Answer (score 4):

Using Swift 4, I don't think you can *automatically* retrieve a `CodingKey` from the corresponding `KeyPath` object but you can always hack your way around it ;)

For instance, in the *same* `User` type Swift source file, add the following `extension`:

```swift
fileprivate extension User {
    static func codingKey(for keyPath: PartialKeyPath<User>) -> CodingKey {
        switch keyPath {
        case \User.id:    return CodingKeys.id
        case \User.email: return CodingKeys.email
        case \User.name:  return CodingKeys.name
        default: fatalError("Unexpected User key path: \(keyPath)")
        }
    }
}
```

then implement the desired `codingKey` API in the constrained `KeyPath` superclass:

```swift
extension PartialKeyPath where Root == User {
    var codingKey: CodingKey {
        return User.codingKey(for: self)
    }
}
```

Finally, the usage follows closely your code:

```swift
let name: CodingKey = (\User.name).codingKey
print("\(name)") // prints "name"
```

This may be a somewhat tedious and error prone solution but, if you only need this capability for handful of types, it's perfectly doable in my opinion ;)

**Caveats**. This hack, of course, won't work for externally defined types given `CodingKeys` enum `private` visibility. (For instance, for all `Codable` types defined by the Swift Standard Library.)

Answer (score -3):

I don't think you can convert property directly to the string but you can achieve similar thing using reflection, but you have to create an instance of the struct:

```
let user = User(id: 1, email: "sample@email.com", name: "just_name")
Mirror(reflecting: user).children.first?.label
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked. What if the user it is using custom keys? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396500/how-do-i-use-custom-keys-with-swift-4s-decodable-protocol/44396824?s=2|4.9822#44396824