# JSON Parsing error - Type 'RecentTvListData' has no subscript members

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm having problems with the **shows["data"]** part of the code and the error reads *Type 'RecentTvListData' has no subscript members*. I have added the structs at the bottom for reference.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {

            let shows =  try
                JSONDecoder().decode(RecentTvListData.self, from: data)
            print(shows)

            self.tvShows = [RecentTvList]()

            if let array = shows["data"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                for dictionary in array {

                var tvShow = RecentTvList()
                    tvShow.title = dictionary["title"] as? String
                    tvShow.poster_url = dictionary["poster_url"] as? String
                    self.tvShows?.append(tvShow)
                }
            }

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing JSON", jsonErr)
        }

    }.resume()

struct RecentTvListData: Decodable  {
    var data: [RecentTvList]
}

struct RecentTvList: Decodable  {
    var title: String?
    var poster_url: String?
}
```

Comment: You just want `self.tvShows = shows.data`, nothing more. The whole point of the new `Codable` API is that you’re dealing with strong types and don’t have to walk through dictionaries type casting.

Comment: Also note that it’s Swift convention for property names to be `lowerCamelCase`, not `snake_case`. If the keys in your JSON differ, you can define your own `CodingKeys`, compare e.g https://stackoverflow.com/q/44396500/2976878

Answer (score 1):

**shows** property is of `RecentTvListData` type, so you need to access like `shows.data`

Small example:

**Structs**

```
struct RecentTvList: Decodable  {
    var title: String?
    var poster_url: String?

    // Custom keys for poster_url
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case poster_url = "poster_url"
    }
}

struct RecentTvListData: Decodable  {
    var data: [RecentTvList]
}
```

**Without loop**

```
var tvShows: [RecentTvList] = []
do {
    let shows = try JSONDecoder().decode(RecentTvListData.self, from: data)
    tvShows = shows.data
} catch {
    debugPrint("Error")
}
```

**With loop**

```
var tvShows: [RecentTvList] = []
do {
    let shows = try JSONDecoder().decode(RecentTvListData.self, from: data)
    for item in shows.data {
        var tvShow = RecentTvList()
        tvShow.title = item.title
        tvShow.poster_url = item.poster_url
        tvShows.append(tvShow)
    }
} catch {
    debugPrint("Error")
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks Sergio :) 
But then I'm struggling with getting the for loop array working. How can I get the tvShow variable appending again?

Comment: I have added more examples like loop and custom keys for properties.