# How to decode a JSON array using Decodable?

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am requesting the API to send me some data which I can successfully retrieve yet I am stuck in the decoding process of it . 
here is the JSON I receive :

```
[  
   {  
      "challenge_id":1,
      "challenge_title":"newchallenge1",
      "challenge_pts_earned":1000,
      "challenge_description":"description1",
      "start_date":"2017-09-24T00:00:00.000Z",
      "end_date":"2017-09-24T00:00:00.000Z",
      "challenge_category_id":1,
      "status_id":2,
      "createdAt":"2017-09-24T17:21:47.000Z",
      "updatedAt":"2017-09-24T09:40:34.000Z"
   },
   {  
      "challenge_id":2,
      "challenge_title":"challenge1",
      "challenge_pts_earned":100,
      "challenge_description":"description1",
      "start_date":"2017-09-24T00:00:00.000Z",
      "end_date":"2017-09-24T00:00:00.000Z",
      "challenge_category_id":1,
      "status_id":0,
      "createdAt":"2017-09-24T17:22:12.000Z",
      "updatedAt":"2017-09-24T09:22:12.000Z"
   },
   {  
      "challenge_id":3,
      "challenge_title":"new eat title",
      "challenge_pts_earned":600000,
      "challenge_description":"haha",
      "start_date":"2017-01-09T00:00:00.000Z",
      "end_date":"2017-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
      "challenge_category_id":2,
      "status_id":0,
      "createdAt":"2017-09-27T17:12:10.000Z",
      "updatedAt":"2017-09-27T09:15:19.000Z"
   }
]
```

and I am trying to create the following structure to decode it :

```
   struct challenge : Codable {
    let  id : String?
    let  title : String?
    let  pointsEarned : String?
    let  description : String?
    let  dayStarted : String?
    let  dayEnded : String?
    let  categoryID : String?
    let  statusID : Int?
    let createdAt : Date?
    let updatedAt : Date?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "challenge_id"
        case title = "challenge_title"
        case pointsEarned = "challenge_pts_earned"
        case description = "challenge_description"
        case dayStarted = "start_date"
        case dayEnded = "end_date"
        case categoryID = "challenge_category_id"
        case statusID = "status_id"
        case createdAt, updatedAt
    }

}
```

And here is my code for the implementation :

```
 var All_challenges : [challenge]?
 let url = URL(string: API.all_challenges.rawValue)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("\(String(describing: response))")
            }
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            guard let result = responseString else { return }
            print(result)
           if let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode([challenge].self , from : data ) {
                self.All_challenges = json

           }

         }
        task.resume()
```

yet when I try to debug it I can never enter the if statement for

```
if let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode([challenge].self,from:data ) {
self.All_challenges = json

 }
```

Please give me some description on where my mistake is , I am very new to JSON paring

Comment: Don't throw away the decoding error by using `try?`, instead catch the error and print it out; it'll tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Unrelated, but it's Swift convention for type names to be `UpperCamelCase` and property & variable variables names to be `lowerCamelCase` (never `snake_case`). If the keys in your JSON differ, [you can define a custom `CodingKeys` enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44396500/2976878). Also do all your properties *need* to be optional? If a given key-value should always be present in the JSON, make it non-optional.

Comment: @Hamish thanks for your comment I have already changed the structure of my structure but I have no idea how to catch the error .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please catch the error and read it

> Type 'String' mismatch.
>   Debug Description: Expected to decode String but found a number instead.

You get that error for `challenge_id`, `challenge_pts_earned`, `challenge_category_id` and `status_id` because the values are `Int` (actually you can notice that already when reading the JSON)

Secondly, the `Date` values cannot be decoded because you didn't provide a date strategy (the default is `TimeInterval`). You have to provide a custom date formatter to decode ISO8601 with fractional seconds.

Finally, as mentioned in the comments use *camelCased* variable names by specifying `CodingKeys` and as the JSON contains always all keys declare the properties as non-optional

```
let jsonString = """
[
{
"challenge_id":1,
"challenge_title":"newchallenge1",
"challenge_pts_earned":1000,
"challenge_description":"description1",
"start_date":"2017-09-24T00:00:00.000Z",
"end_date":"2017-09-24T00:00:00.000Z",
"challenge_category_id":1,
"status_id":2,
"createdAt":"2017-09-24T17:21:47.000Z",
"updatedAt":"2017-09-24T09:40:34.000Z"
},
{
"challenge_id":2,
"challenge_title":"challenge1",
"challenge_pts_earned":100,
"challenge_description":"description1",
"start_date":"2017-09-24T00:00:00.000Z",
"end_date":"2017-09-24T00:00:00.000Z",
"challenge_category_id":1,
"status_id":0,
"createdAt":"2017-09-24T17:22:12.000Z",
"updatedAt":"2017-09-24T09:22:12.000Z"
},
{
"challenge_id":3,
"challenge_title":"new eat title",
"challenge_pts_earned":600000,
"challenge_description":"haha",
"start_date":"2017-01-09T00:00:00.000Z",
"end_date":"2017-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
"challenge_category_id":2,
"status_id":0,
"createdAt":"2017-09-27T17:12:10.000Z",
"updatedAt":"2017-09-27T09:15:19.000Z"
}
]
"""
```

---

```
struct Challenge : Decodable {

//    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
//        case challengeId = "challenge_id"
//        case challengeTitle = "challenge_title"
//        case challengePtsEarned = "challenge_pts_earned"
//        case challengeDescription = "challenge_description"
//        case startDate = "start_date"
//        case endDate = "end_date"
//        case challengeCategoryId = "challenge_category_id"
//        case statusId = "status_id"
//        case createdAt, updatedAt
//    }

    let challengeId : Int
    let challengeTitle : String
    let challengePtsEarned : Int
    let challengeDescription : String
    let startDate : String // or Date
    let endDate : String // or Date
    let challengeCategoryId : Int
    let statusId : Int
    let createdAt : Date
    let updatedAt : Date
}
```

---

```
let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ"
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase 
do {
    let challenges = try decoder.decode([Challenge].self, from: data)
    print(challenges)
} catch { print(error) }
```

---

**Note:**

While developing JSON en-/decoding it's highly recommended to use the full set of error handling. It makes debugging so much easier

```
do {
   try JSONDecoder().decode ...

} catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let context) {
    print(context)
} catch DecodingError.keyNotFound(let key, let context) {
    print("Key '\(key)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch DecodingError.valueNotFound(let value, let context) {
    print("Value '\(value)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(let type, let context)  {
    print("Type '\(type)' mismatch:", context.debugDescription)
    print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

**Edit**

In Swift 4.1 and higher you can omit the CodingKeys by adding the `keyDecodingStrategy`

```
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```

Answer (score 0):

You had several errors in your code. First of all, some of the types of your variables were wrong. All `id`s and `challenge_pts_earned` need to be of type `Int`. You can easily spot this, since in a JSON Strings need to be delimited by quotes. When decoding `Date`s, you also need to specify what date format to use.

`startDate` and `endDate` are also dates, so even though they can be decoded as `String`s, I'd recommend you store them as actual `Date` objects.

Please also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is upperCamelCase for types and lowerCamelCase for variable and function names. You can map your custom variable names to their JSON representation using a custom type conforming to `CodingKey`.

```
struct Challenge : Decodable {
    let id: Int?
    let title: String?
    let pointsEarned: Int?
    let description: String?
    let startDate: String?
    let endDate: String?
    let categoryId: Int?
    let statusId: Int?
    let createdAt: Date?
    let updatedAt: Date?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "challenge_id"
        case title = "challenge_title"
        case pointsEarned = "challenge_pts_earned"
        case description = "challenge_description"
        case startDate = "start_date"
        case endDate = "end_date"
        case categoryId = "challenge_category_id"
        case statusId = "status_id"
        case createdAt
        case updatedAt
    }

    static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return df
    }
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(Challenge.dateFormatter)
    let decoded = try decoder.decode([Challenge].self, from: jsonArrayResponse.data(using: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```