# Swift 4 Decode json with the ' - ' letter

Tags: json, swift, swift4, decodable

How does the swift 4 Decodable protocol work with the ' - ' letter?
For example:

```
[{
    "trigger": {
        "url-filter": "webkit.org",
        "resource-type": ["image"]
 },
    "action": {
        "selector": "#logo",
        "type": "block"
    }
}]
```

In My Swift Class:

```
struct blockerJson : Decodable {
    let action : action
    let trigger : trigger

    struct action : Decodable {
        let selector : String
        let type : String
    }

    struct trigger : Decodable {
        let urlFilter : String
        let resourceType : String
    }
}
```

I don't know how to change the class, but the json can't change...

Comment: It works like any other supported character.

Comment: You need to do it by yourself as per your needs in a json response that you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use custom keys with Swift 4's Decodable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396500/how-do-i-use-custom-keys-with-swift-4s-decodable-protocol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code parses trigger block

```
struct Trigger: Decodable {
    var urlFilter: String
    var resourceType: [String]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case urlFilter = "url-filter"
        case resourceType = "resource-type"
    }
}
```

Comment: Xcode show error with [Type 'trigger' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable']...

Comment: @LeoWu  Please note the typo `urlFillter` (two `l`) vs `urlFilter` (one `l`)

Comment: @vadian 10x fixed