# Is there a way to customise declarations for variable naming in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, variables, naming-conventions

I'm trying to initialise a value in dictionary as follow,

```
var og:image: String
```

But after `og:` it tries to assign the type considering `og` as the variable to site_name, which is obviously wrong.

> Is there a way to assign `og:image` as variable to `String` type using
>   special or escape characters?

In [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/decimal-digits) to this, apple does not provide any meaningful explanations to variable naming conventions in such a situation.

Edit-1:

Here is code snippet to clarify dictionary `usage` is in JSON parsing data structure,

```
struct Metadata: Decodable{
    var metatags : [enclosedTags]
}
struct enclosedTags: Decodable{
    var image: String
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var og:site_name: String
}
```

Comment: cant use in declaration but you can append in the string at a later stage as value.

Comment: Which *dictionary* are you talking of? – And the valid identifier characters are documented at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID412, `:` is not among them.

Comment: @MartinR I have edited to shed some light on the dictionary part.

Comment: @HamzaIqbal You want to use a custom `CodingKeys` enum for that, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/44396500/2976878

Comment: Your question is a good example for an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :) – The above link from Hamish solves your *real* problem.

Comment: Rightly as pointed, I have corrected question title to clarify the problem@MartinR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out swift has it's own feature in terms of naming specificity of variables in structs i.e. `CodingKeys`, so in terms for me the below naming convention worked,

```
   struct Metadata: Decodable{
        var metatags: [enclosedTags]

    }
        struct enclosedTags: Decodable{
            let image: String
            let title: String
            let description: String
            let siteName: String

            private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey{
                case image = "og:image", title = "og:title", description = "og:description", siteName = "og:site_name"
            }
```

This was rightfully pointed out by `@hamish` in comments (Thanks mate!)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use : (colon). But if you really want:

```
var ogCOLONimage: String
```

Joking apart. You could use a Dictionary or something like that:

```
var images: [String: String] = ["og:image" : "your string"]
```

Now you can access your `og:image` data with `images["og:image"]`.

Comment: In the current context, it does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Swift allow you to use almost any character when naming variables. You can even use Unicode characters.

However, there are a few restrictions:

> Constant and variable names can’t contain whitespace characters, mathematical symbols, arrows, private-use (or invalid) Unicode code points, or line- and box-drawing characters. Nor can they begin with a number, although numbers may be included elsewhere within the name.

Said that, it is not possible to use `:` in the name of a variable. However, you can use a Unicode character similar to that symbol. Depending on what you want it for, this may be a valid solution.

Here you have a list of the Unicode characters similar to `:` that can be used in the name of a variable:

- `︓`
- `﹕`
- `：`

(https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/based/U+003A)

Based on the example you provided it would be this:

```
struct Metadata: Decodable{
    var metatags : [enclosedTags]
}
struct enclosedTags: Decodable{
    var image: String
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var og：site_name: String
}
```

Comment: Then how would you select the specific unicode in xcode?

Comment: You can just copy-paste it

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it, as the unicode that you used was wrong and also using `CodingKeys` is makes world a better place ;)

Comment: I didn't know about CodingKeys, I'm glad you finally found a solution for it