# The `convertFromSnakeCase` strategy doesn't work with custom `CodingKeys` in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, codable, jsondecoder

I try to use Swift 4.1's new feature to convert snake-case to camelCase during JSON decoding.

Here is the [example](https://gist.github.com/howardev/96388525f3c57673810ade608160f799):

```
struct StudentInfo: Decodable {
    internal let studentID: String
    internal let name: String
    internal let testScore: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case studentID = "student_id"
        case name
        case testScore
    }
}

let jsonString = """
{"student_id":"123","name":"Apple Bay Street","test_score":"94608"}
"""

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let decoded = try decoder.decode(StudentInfo.self, from: Data(jsonString.utf8))
    print(decoded)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

I need provide custom `CodingKeys` since the `convertFromSnakeCase` strategy can't infer capitalization for acronyms or initialisms (such as `studentID`) but I expect the `convertFromSnakeCase` strategy will still work for `testScore`. However, the decoder throws error ("No value associated with key CodingKeys") and it seems that I can't use `convertFromSnakeCase` strategy and custom `CodingKeys` at the same time. Am I missing something?

Comment: You want `case studentID = "studentId"` (compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396824/2976878) – the decoder applies the key strategy before consulting the coding keys, so it transforms `"student_id"` to `"studentId"`.

Comment: Thank you @Hamish! That works!

Comment: @Rob Will do when I get a moment (if nobody else posts an answer in the mean time, that is)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The key strategies for `JSONDecoder` (and `JSONEncoder`) are applied to all keys in the payload – including those that you provide a custom coding key for. When decoding, the JSON key will first be mapped using the given key strategy, and then the decoder will consult the `CodingKeys` for the given type being decoded.

In your case, the `student_id` key in your JSON will be mapped to `studentId` by `.convertFromSnakeCase`. The exact algorithm for the transformation is [given in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder.keydecodingstrategy/2949105-convertfromsnakecase):

> 1. Capitalize each word that follows an underscore.
> 2. Remove all underscores that aren't at the very start or end of the string.
> 3. Combine the words into a single string.
>
> The following examples show the result of applying this strategy:
>
> `fee_fi_fo_fum`
>
> Converts to: `feeFiFoFum`
>
> `feeFiFoFum`
>
> Converts to: `feeFiFoFum`
>
> `base_uri`
>
> Converts to: `baseUri`

You therefore need to update your `CodingKeys` to match this:

```
internal struct StudentInfo: Decodable, Equatable {
  internal let studentID: String
  internal let name: String
  internal let testScore: String

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case studentID = "studentId"
    case name
    case testScore
  }
}
```

Comment: Woah! Many thanks for pointing out the ORDER of the conversions!

Comment: Really helpful answer, although the result is that I'm not going to use `keyDecodingStrategy` because it makes the code considerably less readable.

Comment: The way this works is terrible. Custom coding keys should be treated exactly as that: _custom_.