# Converting from snake case to camel case using keyDecodingStrategy

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I am trying to use **Codable** to automatically parse incoming `JSON` into my models. It is working fine, but then I learnt about `_keyDecodingStrategy_`, and wanted to use this. It is working great and able to lessen my code as I do not have to write `CodingKeys` enum for my models.

But now the problem is a new variable sent from server. The variable is *`post_url_110x110`*.

I thought it will convert to *`postUrl110x110`*, but it doesn't. Do help me into its `camelCase` conversion or suggest if I should avoid automatic conversion in this case.

Comment: You should update your question to include the actual JSON that you need to decode along with your data model and the code you use for decoding.

Comment: `.keyDecodingStrategy` and `CodingKeys` can be used side by side at a time. And you have to use both of them. The downside is you have to cover all the cases for `CodingKeys`. Just provide the raw values of those properties which fail when `.convertFromSnakeCase` is applied. Leave other cases (meaning, you don't have to write the raw values). To know more see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49888925/3687801)

Comment: Yes. KeyDecodingStrategy is an improvisation on my existing json decoding using Codable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work for you if you rename your data model property from `postUrl110x110` to `postUrl110X110` with capital X. I know it's not ideal solution but it's worth noting. Check the example below:

```
struct DataItem: Codable {
    var itemId: String
    var postUrl110X110: String
}

let json = """
{
    "item_id": "abcd",
    "post_url_110x110": "https://example.org/image.png"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

print(try! decoder.decode(DataItem.self, from: json))
```

Comment: Wonderful Martin. Thanks a lot. This was what I exactly wanted. I could change my model name, but had no control on the incoming json. Now I am able to seamlessly parse json directly to my model using Codable + keyDecodingStrategy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [tool](https://app.quicktype.io?share=mKWGmMWuTiOE1hd9qypO).

**Sample input**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

- If you need further assistance then let me know.

Comment: From my point of view this answer is not valid. Amit is asking for the way using keyDecodingStrategy without writing CodingKeys manually