# "No value associated with key CodingKeys" error always thrown

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I've got this Decodable struct:

```
struct MyDecodableTester: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let snakeCase: String
    let mappedCodingKey: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case snakeCase
        case mappedCodingKey = "code_key"
    }

    static func decode(from data: Data) -> Self? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        do {
            return try decoder.decode(Self.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(">>> Error: \(error)")
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

I tried calling the `decode(from data:)` function, using this JSON:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "name",
"snake_case": "snake_case",
"code_key": "code_key"
}
```

The problem is, it always throws this error:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "code_key", intValue: nil),
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No
>   value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"code_key\",
>   intValue: nil) (\"code_key\").", underlyingError: nil))

Even when I added the `init(from coder:)` function below, it always crashes because `mappedCodingKey` is nil.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    id = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self,
                                           forKey: .id)!
    name = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)!
    snakeCase = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self,
                                             forKey: .snakeCase)!
    mappedCodingKey = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self,
                                            forKey: .mappedCodingKey)!
}
```

I believe my JSON is already correct so I don't know why the error happened. Is there anything that I've missed here? How do I fix this?

Comment: can you try this again after commenting out the keyDecodingStrategy?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [The `convertFromSnakeCase` strategy doesn't work with custom `CodingKeys` in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49881621/1187415).

Comment: @MartinR Ah you are right. Thanks.