# How to change JSON key name Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

In my application I have used the same keyname to get data everywhere, now in json response that data is same but in one place the keyname is changed so I want to rename the keyname of the array in my json this is what I am getting searched on stack overflow but unable to find any reliable way please guide me any good way to do it

```
{"status":"success","msg":"deleted","pro_data":[]}
```

I want JSON with these keys:

```
{"status":"success","msg":"deleted","Images":[]}
```

Comment: you can use swift4?

Comment: yes i am using swift4 i want to rename key after the getting response

Comment: yes you can it in swift 4 you need to search about advance JSON parsing in swift4

Comment: can u post some piece of code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use custom keys with Swift 4's Decodable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396500/how-do-i-use-custom-keys-with-swift-4s-decodable-protocol)

Answer (score 7):

you can use Codable to create JSON model and in that you can customise you key.

> I assume your JSON response **(`{"status":"success","msg":"deleted","pro_data":[]}`)** available in `Data` format.

So, See the following code which are used to create JSON model for your data.

```
struct WSModel: Codable {
    var status  : String?
    var msg     : Int?
    var Images  : [Any]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case currentPage    = "status"
        case msg            = "msg"
        case Images         = "pro_data"
    }
}
```

Due to there aren't any data type inside your array I have keep **`Any`** type of data.This code is work for when keys in response are "status", "msg", "pro_data".

Try this code and let me know still an issue. I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your issue is that you want to continue to use `"Images":[]` key, without having to change rest of your code.

In your JSON response that you want to change, you can try something like this.

```
response["Images"] = response["pro_data"]
```

Comment: @Jhony, When you do this, and then print your object `response`, doest it not have the new key?