# JSONDecoder fails to find key that is present

Tags: ios, swift, foundation, jsondecoder

When attempting to parse the response from the [Create Team](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create) call in Github's REST api, `JSONDecoder` fails when parsing many of the snake cased keys for a Repository. When decoding through `JSONSerialization`, it is able to find all keys without problem.

For example, when running in Playground in Xcode 11.0 (11A420a), the decoding fails when decoding with `JSONDecoder`.

```swift
import Foundation

let jsonData = """
{
"id": 12345,
"name": "swift",
"ssh_url": "git@github.com:apple/swift.git"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct ExampleModel: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let sshURL: String
}

let jsonObject = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [String: Any]
print("JSONSerialization:", jsonObject["id"]!, jsonObject["name"]!, jsonObject["ssh_url"]!)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let decodedObject = try! decoder.decode(ExampleModel.self, from: jsonData) // Fails here
print("JSONDecoder:", decodedObject.id, decodedObject.name, decodedObject.sshURL)

// Output:
//
// JSONSerialization: 12345 swift git@github.com:apple/swift.git
// Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "sshURL", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"sshURL\", intValue: nil) (\"sshURL\"), converted to ssh_url.", underlyingError: nil)): file MyPlayground.playground, line 22
```

Is there something different that I should be doing to parse this value?

Swift version:

```
Apple Swift version 5.1 (swiftlang-1100.0.270.13 clang-1100.0.33.7)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
```

Comment: Your variable name doesn't match the JSON key, you can see this answer for some alternatives https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396824/725628

Comment: Try `sshUrl` Instead of `sshURL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `sshURL` to `sshUrl`. The `keyDecodingStartegy` will transform `sshURL` into `ssh_URL`, which doesn't match your key. `sshUrl` will be transformed into `ssh_url`, which will match your key.