# Decoding an API response in Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire to decode objects, and my JSON looks like this

```
{
  "wallet": {
    "public_key": "ADDRESS",
    "name": "My test wallet",
    "id": "-MQ9NdAyMaK3WQfSOYZW",
    "owner": "Kca8BNHy8FemIxPO7FWBSLE8XKN2",
    "currency": "ME",
    "metadata": {
      "legacy_address": "WHAT",
      "x_pub_address": "SOMETHING COOL"
    }
  },
  "secrets": {
    "wif": "SOMETHING",
    "private_key": "SOMETHING ELSE",
    "mnemonic": "YOU WISH"
  }
}
```

My Swift looks like this:

```
class Response: Codable {

   var wallet: Wallet
   var secrets: [String: String]
}

class Wallet: Codable {
   var publicKey: String
   var name: String
   var id: String
   var owner: String
   var currency: String
   var metadata: [String: String]

   enum WalletKeys: String, CodingKey{
      case publicKey = "public_key",
      case name, 
      case id 
      case owner, 
      case currency,
      case metadata
   }
}
```

I'm getting a `keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "publicKey"))` error, and I dont know why. Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: you have to add all your variable on enum WalletKeys: String, CodingKey, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396500/how-do-i-use-custom-keys-with-swift-4s-decodable-protocol

Comment: @luffy_064 I tried this, same error.

Comment: case publicKey = "public_key"
 case name, id owner, currency, metadata , please read the link.

Comment: Yeah @luffy_064 I read the link, updated my Swift file above and in my code, still getting the same issue

Comment: It is painful to hardcode constructs to map the json structure. You should try https://app.quicktype.io/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your decoder `keyDecodingStrategy` property value to `.convertFromSnakeCase`:

---

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let wallet: Wallet
    let secrets: Secrets
}
```

---

```
struct Secrets: Codable {
    let wif: String
    let privateKey: String
    let mnemonic: String
}
```

---

```
struct Wallet: Codable {
    let publicKey: String
    let name: String
    let id: String
    let owner: String
    let currency: String
    let metadata: Metadata
}
```

---

```
struct Metadata: Codable {
    let legacyAddress: String
    let xPubAddress: String
}
```

---

---

```
let json = """
{
  "wallet": {
    "public_key": "ADDRESS",
    "name": "My test wallet",
    "id": "-MQ9NdAyMaK3WQfSOYZW",
    "owner": "Kca8BNHy8FemIxPO7FWBSLE8XKN2",
    "currency": "ME",
    "metadata": {
      "legacy_address": "WHAT",
      "x_pub_address": "SOMETHING COOL"
    }
  },
  "secrets": {
    "wif": "SOMETHING",
    "private_key": "SOMETHING ELSE",
    "mnemonic": "YOU WISH"
  }
}
"""
```

---

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let root = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: Data(json.utf8))
    print(root)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

This will print:

> Response(wallet: Wallet(publicKey: "ADDRESS", name: "My test wallet", id: "-MQ9NdAyMaK3WQfSOYZW", owner: "Kca8BNHy8FemIxPO7FWBSLE8XKN2", currency: "ME", metadata: Metadata(legacyAddress: "WHAT", xPubAddress: "SOMETHING COOL")), secrets: __lldb_expr_1.Secrets(wif: "SOMETHING", privateKey: "SOMETHING ELSE", mnemonic: "YOU WISH"))

Comment: Tried this, getting the same error. Also this shouldn't be the case anyway because I set custom coding keys.

Comment: @Randomuser123 it should be called CodingKeys. I will edit my post

Comment: Yup this worked, also another easier & shorter fix was just setting the enum to be of type `CodingKeys` :))

Comment: I usually prefer setting the property. Just personal preference.