# How to pass CodingKeys into a function outside a class, as an array not an enum?

Tags: swift, codable

I have implemented custom JSON decoding for some classes in my project. I've set up the usual CodingKeys enum and implemented custom encode and decode functions. This all works fine.

But I've also implemented a few convenience functions for the decoding process that catch any errors thrown by JSONDecoder's KeyedDecodingContainer and return something sane. Because these functions don't need to vary between classes, I want to move them out of the class but most examples define the coding keys as hard-coded enums in the class.

For those asking: There's a good reason that the members are not optionals: You can't bind to optionals in SwiftUI, so you wouldn't be able to display this structure in a UI for editing.

Here's the class to be decoded:

```
class User : Equatable, Codable
{
    var ID: String = ""
    var pw: String = ""
    var username:  String = ""
    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""
    var EMail: String = ""
    var phoneNbr: String = ""
    var avatarURL: String = ""
    var mediaServiceID: String = ""
    var validated: Bool = false // E-mail is confirmed.

    // Equatable
    static func == (lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool
    {
        return lhs.ID == rhs.ID
    }

    // Codable
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
    {
        case ID = "ID"
        case pw = "pw"
        case username = "username"
        case firstName = "firstName"
        case lastName = "lastName"
        case EMail = "EMail"
        case phoneNbr = "phoneNbr"
        case avatarURL = "avatarURL"
        case mediaServiceID = "mediaServiceID"
        case validated = "validated"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        var container: KeyedDecodingContainer<CodingKeys>
        do
        {
            container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        }
        
        ID =                safeStringDecode(container: container, forKey: .ID)
        pw =                safeStringDecode(container: container, forKey: .pw)
        username =          safeStringDecode(container: container, forKey: .username)
        firstName =         safeStringDecode(container: container, forKey: .firstName)
        lastName =          safeStringDecode(container: container, forKey: .lastName)
        EMail =             safeStringDecode(container: container, forKey: .EMail)
        phoneNbr =          safeStringDecode(container: container, forKey: .phoneNbr)
        avatarURL =         safeStringDecode(container: container, forKey: .avatarURL)
        mediaServiceID =    safeStringDecode(container: container, forKey: .mediaServiceID)
        validated =         safeBoolDecode(container: container, forKey: .validated)
    }

    func safeStringDecode(container: KeyedDecodingContainer<CodingKeys>, forKey: CodingKeys) -> String
    {
        var result: String
        do
        {
            result = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: forKey)
        }
        catch
        {
            result = ""
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    func safeBoolDecode(container: KeyedDecodingContainer<CodingKeys>, forKey: CodingKeys) -> Bool
    {
        // First try int, because that's what MySQL/MariaDB return for bools.
        var result: Int
        do
        {
            result = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: forKey)
            return result == 1
        }
        catch
        {
            // Let's see if it's a 'true'/'false' string.
            var stringResult: String
            do
            {
                stringResult = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: forKey)
                return stringResult == "true"
            }
            catch
            {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to move those safeDecode methods out of this class and into a general utility namespace. But that means I can't hard-code the coding keys as an enum in the class, so I need to pass them in as an array or dictionary. It seems like it should be simple, but thus far I haven't seen a succinct solution. #3 in this post seems close, but I don't really understand some of the logic: [How do I use custom keys with Swift 4's Decodable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396500/how-do-i-use-custom-keys-with-swift-4s-decodable-protocol?rq=3)

The rationale for the "safeDecode" functions was that decoding the object would fail entirely if any of the values were missing or nil, which is entirely possible because those columns are nullable in my database. To prevent that without the convenience functions, I thought I'd have to couch the decoding attempt for every member in a separate do/catch pair... incredibly tedious. But I was unaware of the try? syntax to catch this line-by-line. Thus now I only need the Boolean helper to handle different databases' Boolean types. I put that in a KeyedDecodingContainer extension as @Alexander kindly suggested.

Comment: Trust me, this `safeStringDecode` seems like a good idea, but it’ll have you pulling your hair out. There’s nothing safe about `””`, instead of wondering why a field is nil, you’ll be wondering why it’s an empty string, but that hasn’t actually solved anything. The resulting object is still fundamentally invalid.

Comment: Also, the `ID = safeStringDecode(container: container, forKey: .ID)` can just be expressed with `ID = (try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: forKey) ?? ""`. That's even shorter than calling the helper, so it's not really worth having, even if you did want `""` as defaults (which again, I caution against)

Comment: Thank you for these observations. The boolean case is the most important of these helpers. The expression of booleans varies between databases, which is why I created these helpers in the first place. The string case is to handle empty or null DB columns; the object I'm decoding isn't invalid simply because these fields are empty.

Comment: Final comment on the nil vs. default-empty-string choice: The members were not optionals because you can't bind to those in SwiftUI, for presentation in a UI.

Comment: You don't bind to them directly. You map the binding into a non-optional binding, by substituting a default, or more often, taking a different course of action. For example, in an email template, you might choose the greeting like to be `"Hello, ...` instead of "Hello \(name)", ...`. Notice the distinction isn't achievable merely with a default value.

Comment: The problem is that those bindings are not bi-directional. So presenting a UI for editing is not practical, since you have to implement a verbose workaround with get/set methods for every optional member of a class. At that point you might as just well make them non-optional.

Comment: That makes sense in the context where it’s editable. It’s more often to be reading data than setting it, and that’s where my email example comes in

Comment: Indeed. But Apple evangelizes the "single source of truth" as the grail that SwiftUI is supposed to deliver, and it is woefully unprepared to support it because of this limitation.

Comment: Heh, I just ran into [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/mildlyinfuriating/comments/199etj9/) where Epic Games made the same mistake: `"Hello, :"`

Comment: Except they are bi-directional...

Comment: Oh that was silly, I was thinking of Combine publishers haha. Ignore me :)

Comment: Ha, NP. Thanks for the follow-up though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: I would strongly caution against providing default values like this. If you end up with an object like `User(username: "", firstName: "", lastName: "", EMail: "", phoneNbr: "", ...)`, what's safe about that? It's nonsense that these helper functions have allowed to silently slip through the cracks.

Nonetheless, I'll answer the question more generally, to show how code like this can be shared in Swift.

## Approach 1: mix it in with a protocol extension

```swift
// An empty marker protocol, which requires the conforming type to
// be decodable
protocol DecodingHelpers: Decodable {
  associatedtype CodingKeys: CodingKey
}

// Mark `User` with the protocol
extension User: DecodingHelpers {}

// Extend all `DecodingHelpers`-conforming types with the helper functions
extension DecodingHelpers {
  func safeStringDecode(container: KeyedDecodingContainer<CodingKeys>, forKey: CodingKeys) -> String {
    (try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: forKey)) ?? ""
  }
  
  func safeBoolDecode(container: KeyedDecodingContainer<CodingKeys>, forKey: CodingKeys) -> Bool {
    do {
      // First try int, because that's what MySQL/MariaDB return for bools.
      return try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: forKey) == 1
    }
    catch {
      do {
        // Let's see if it's a 'true'/'false' string.
        return try container.decode(String.self, forKey: forKey) == "true"
      }
      catch {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Approach 2: Move these to an extension

Instead of dumping these helpers as methods on all the models that use them, you can instead just change them into extensions on `KeyedDecodingContainer`:

```swift
extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
  func safeStringDecode(forKey: K) -> String {
    (try? decode(String.self, forKey: forKey)) ?? ""
  }
  
  func safeBoolDecode(forKey: K) -> Bool {
    do {
      // First try int, because that's what MySQL/MariaDB return for bools.
      return try decode(Int.self, forKey: forKey) == 1
    }
    catch {
      do {
        // Let's see if it's a 'true'/'false' string.
        return try decode(String.self, forKey: forKey) == "true"
      }
      catch {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
}

// Usage:
class User: Equatable, Codable
  // ...

  required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container =  try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    
    ID             = container.safeStringDecode(forKey: .ID)
    pw             = container.safeStringDecode(forKey: .pw)
    username       = container.safeStringDecode(forKey: .username)
    firstName      = container.safeStringDecode(forKey: .firstName)
    lastName       = container.safeStringDecode(forKey: .lastName)
    EMail          = container.safeStringDecode(forKey: .EMail)
    phoneNbr       = container.safeStringDecode(forKey: .phoneNbr)
    avatarURL      = container.safeStringDecode(forKey: .avatarURL)
    mediaServiceID = container.safeStringDecode(forKey: .mediaServiceID)
    validated      = container.safeBoolDecode(forKey: .validated)
  }
}
```

## Approach 3: Use property wrappers

This is my favourite approach, because it can completely remove the need to define a custom `init(from:)` initializer!

Check out the `Default` macro from the `MetaCodable` package, for reference: https://github.com/SwiftyLab/MetaCodable/blob/a6011c3337f573b04b29b8591b507de7e6e4ed8d/Sources/MetaCodable/Default.swift

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to post that. To answer your question: A User object with a bunch of unpopulated fields is valid if the application is prepared to handle it. Consider the new-user-creation process. If you force people to fill out a big-ass form up-front before they can proceed, you're going to face massive attrition. Sad but known fact about "friction" in the "on-boarding" process. So you may create a User entity with the bare minimum data at first, then ask the user to complete his profile after confirming his registration. That's exactly the case here.

Comment: But is that really the responsibility of the decoding, isn't that a UI responsibility?

Comment: @Oscar That's what optionals are for. The type system will help you remember to check that an `Optional<String>` might be `nil` (not yet filled out). It can't help you remember to check that a `String` is `""`. I _guarantee_ you that you will run into bugs caused by not checking for these empty strings everywhere. Prematurely defaulted values are bad. Bad bad bad.

Comment: You might to need be able to model several different kinds of "no value", such as "not set yet", vs "set and not applicable", and "set and filled in". In that case, instead of `Optional`, you can make yourself a similar enum of your own like `OptionalFormField<T>` that's `.notSet`, `.notApplicable` or `.set(value: T)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. @Alexander Originally I did make most of the members of User optional, but have since made them solid for reasons I can't remember at the moment. But these are non-essential fields (nullable in the DB) that I will not cause bugs if empty... with only a couple of exceptions that I'd have to check for nulls in anyway. And I did make an enum just as you suggest for use in the UI. Anyway, I may put these back to optionals to see why I found that unacceptable in the first place. The Boolean decoder is definitely necessary, regardless.

Comment: Glad to see this helps :) "that I will not cause bugs if empty..." I give you my personal guarantee that you'll end up with some UI that renders `"Good afternoon Mr. , Let's confirm your contact info, is this correct? email: , phone-number: "` where the fields are empty instead of filled in

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I would say no, because the user may quit the application before "filling out" his user details. Upon relaunch, we need to pull that user's record from the database and tolerate its incompleteness.

Comment: @Alexander Ha ha, that is certainly a reasonable prediction! But I have to allow the record to exist temporarily with either empty or null entries for some of these things, so it's on me to check. I actually did find a solution to passing decoding keys around (using a dictionary of custom CodingKey-compliant structs), but I'm going to try your extension idea. I was hoping someone would jump in with an alternative solution like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256570/discussion-between-alexander-and-oscar).