# How can we have "one source of truth" when SwiftUI doesn't support optionals?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-optionals

I need to display and allow the editing of a class whose members are mostly optional. This does not appear to be a scenario that SwiftUI envisions, despite Apple propagating the "single source of truth" mantra in its SwiftUI tutorials. What is the expected approach?

Take this class, for example, which represents a user:

```
class User : Equatable, Codable, ObservableObject
{
    var ID: String
    var username:  String
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var EMail: String?
    var phoneNbr: String?
    var avatarURL: String?
    var mediaServiceID: String?
    var validated: Bool = false
...
}
```

I can't directly show a form to fill this thing out in SwiftUI, because you can't bind text fields to optionals. Most of the published workarounds to that involve using ***let*** to create a non-optional variable if the member isn't nil; but this is unworkable because that won't populate a nil member if someone enters text in the text field.
Apple docs talk about custom binding, which would probably work to populate an optional member. That means doing this in the SwiftUI view to set the object's username, for example:

```
@State private var      tempUser = User()

private var username: Binding<String>
{
    Binding { tempUser.username ?? "" }
    set: { newName in
        tempUser.username = newName
    }
}
```

But that means setting up one of these verbose methods for every single optional member of every class I want to show in a UI. At that point I might as well just make a shadow structure that's all non-optionals that I can bind directly to. Or just make all the members non-optional and just face the fact that optionals are done with in the age of SwiftUI.

Or is there some succinct approach I'm missing here? Thanks for any insight.

Comment: The question as you put it ("Are optionals basically over in the SwiftUI era?") is opinion-based and goes against SO guidelines. Coming back to optional strings and `Text`, as you said, `Text` accepts only non-optional strings, and it's up to you how you design your code and UI: You can replace `nil` strings before they reach a `View` and display empty `Text` or use something like `if let string { Text(string) }` and don't display `Text` for `nil` strings.

Comment: You can add that binding in an extension to Optional to make your code cleaner. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57041232/9223839

Comment: @lazarevzubov Thanks, but that does not fulfill the intended functionality of SwiftUI and its bindings in supporting "one source of truth," because it is not bi-directional.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks. That's what I ended up doing. I also added versions for other basic types.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what do you mean by "the intended functionality of SwiftUI," but the trick pointed out by @JoakimDanielson does exactly what I suggested: It replaces `nil` strings with empty ones before they reach UI.

Comment: It does more than that, though. It provides BI-DIRECTIONAL support of optionals. Replacing an optional with a temporary local "solid" variable doesn't update the original (optional) source when the user types something in the text field in the UI. That is the intended functionality of SwiftUI bindings.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to display and allow the editing of a class whose members are mostly optional.

That has always been a bad design, not just SwiftUI. In what way is nil different from empty? From your binding, you're indicating they're the same. If that's the case, then it should never have been Optional in the first place. It should just have been a normal String and made empty.

You're correct that SwiftUI can make this kind of bad design even harder than it's been in the past, but it was always hard. Redesign your type to only use Optionals for things where nil has a distinct meaning.

Of particular interest is that ID is optional. How can this type work with no ID?

To the headline question of whether Optionals are over, that absolutely is not the case. Optionals are as much a critical part of Swift as they've ever been. But representing "empty" as two different values (an empty thing like "", and also nil) is not something SwiftUI (or Swift) encourages. It will tend to be a pain.

That said, macros and property wrappers can write the code for you if you need it. I recommend fixing your data before going down that path, however.

Comment: Plenty of people disagree with you, and you can get a sample here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77803780/how-to-pass-codingkeys-into-a-function-outside-a-class-as-an-array-not-an-enum You're basically impugning the entire language feature. Nil is different from empty in that it has not been set, meaning that (for example) we haven't completed an attempt to load this user from a database. And in a database table that supports nulls for some columns, the class likewise supports that for some members. I don't permit a null ID. I guess I should change it here so people don't fixate on it.

Comment: My design is still evolving, so the point is not to fixate on any particular member but rather how to deal with optionals that are represented as editable fields.

Comment: If your Optionals represent a different value than empty, in your case "unloaded," then Optional is completely appropriate. Your code doesn't show that distinction, and this is an incredibly common design error. I'm sorry if I read too much into your code.

Comment: This raises the question though of how you want your editable field to work. How will your UI distinguish between "not yet set" and "set to empty?" You seem to be squashing the two together (which is the common design error). I would assume that unloaded things should not be editable, but perhaps you have a different design. SwiftUI provides not "default" way to do this because it really is a UX design choice. If you want to treat nil as empty (and likely modify it to empty in some cases even if not changed), then your Binding is correct. Property wrappers might make it less code.

Comment: I certainly did not mean to discourage the use of Optionals. I am a huge fan. I've been singing their praises and encouraging people to use them correctly for years: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1Tayh4unMw  I don't think Alexander's points conflict with what I've said here. If null in the database is its own value, with an independent meaning from empty (so the UI should show that somehow), then use Optional. If null and empty are treated the same, don't.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. In my case, there is a state where the user has been added to the database (necessary in order to generate and return an ID per my chosen scheme on the server) but still has some "work to do" after the initial record makes the round-trip to the server. I use nils to detect this "unfinished" condition and present the appropriate UI for the user to provide (or opt not to provide) more information once his account is confirmed. Anyway, the design is still evolving. I'm off to watch your video now...